# Ordenar un array por proximidad a un número

Tags: javascript, array

Necesito ordenar un array tal que la diferencia entre sus elementos (númericos) tengan la menor diferencia a un determinado valor.

Ej. Si el valor es 10:

```
let arr = [2,4,23,33];
```

Necesito que quede así:

```
[4,2,23,33]
```

Porque

```
10 - 4  = 6;
10 - 2  = 8;
23 - 10 = 13;
33 - 10 = 23;
```

Gracias desde ya

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Ahí posteé una respuesta, usé un poco la cabeza.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tratando de simplificar un poco el código:

```js
function diffSort(value, arr){
  return arr.sort((x, y) => Math.abs(x-value)>Math.abs(y-value));
}

console.log(diffSort(10, [2,66,4,33,6,23,99,9.5,55]));
```

Comment: Uh quedó mejor así. Aunque como no soy un genio con JS no entiendo el return del callback. Retorna un booleano, entendía que necesitaba que sea un número.

Comment: En realidad hace una conversión implícita, pero puedes reemplazar el `>` por un `-` y obtendrás el mismo resultado en la ordenación.

Comment: Marco la tuya como apropiada. Veo que funciona y es menos código.

Answer (score 3):

Bueno, pensé 5 minutos y lo resolví. Posteo por si les sirve

```js
function ordenar(value, arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(x, y) {
    let difx = Math.abs(parseFloat(x) - value);
    let dify = Math.abs(parseFloat(y) - value);
    if (difx < dify) return -1;
    if (difx == dify) return 0;
    return 1;
  });
}


let array = [2, 4, 23, 33];

console.log(ordenar(10, array));
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
 
function diffSort(n,...arr){
var f = 0, max = arr[0].length, na = parseInt(n, 10), sorted = [], torever = 0,
    fn = [];
for(;f<max;f++){
var index = 0, actual = arr[0][f];
if(actual > na) torever++;  
while(n-actual < (na-sorted[sorted.length-1-index])) {index++;} 
sorted.splice(sorted.length-index,0 , actual);  
}  
  for(var i=0;i<torever;i++){
  fn.unshift(sorted[i]);    
  }
  var b = sorted.concat(fn);
  b.splice(0,torever)
  return b;
}

console.log(diffSort(10, [2,66,4,33,6,23,99,9.5,55]))
```

Comment: A disfrutar pensando otro rato más jeje, cuando lo tenga lo editaré

Comment: Listo, aunque intentaré mejorarlo, ya que no uso ningún sort nativo

Comment: Si te interesa disfrutar pensando un rato más, podés probar con `11` ;-)  ... Una buena estrategia es usar Math.abs(), como respondió el autor de la pregunta.

Comment: El número 11 en donde? lo coloqué en el array y en el número de referencia y sigue funcionando

Comment: Además me dí cuenta, de que este algoritmo también sirve para ordenar array descendiente y ascendientemente, con el punto de referencia, que internamente podría ser 0 o 1, eso daria igual

Comment: En el array. El `11` está a 1 del 10, por lo que se debería ordenar en la 2da posición (después del `9.5`)

Comment: oh oh... bueno creó que llegaré atrasado a la escuela, lo intentaré durante mi recreo jajjaja, (creo que tendré que pensar todo denuevo), buen dia!!